# Help understanding why my question was closed

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376418/how-to-integrate-way2sms-in-android-application?noredirect=1

I had asked poorly, without trying anything, hence it was put on hold. But, on subsequent days I researched and then edited the post with my progress and things I tried. The question was closed after 5 days of being on hold.

I tried to flag the post but the moderators didn't think it appropriate to reopen it. Can anyone explain to me what I am still missing?

Comment: It looks broad and here we can not tell each and every step for integration process, So you need to contact way2sms for integration or read their help page.

Comment: there is no official support for the integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing reason is **unclear of what you're asking for**. Which means, that the question is puzzly for the readers to read and understand.

#### Reasons

You're making alot of assumptions, such as Question 1 and then its part a for clarification and so on. Which is not allowed here, you need to be precise as much as you can, you must specify your problem clearly to get a clear answer! :)

You might want to go here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

It is better to ask the question in a very short, but to the point form!

#### Your question would have been; in simple words

How can I integrate my Android application so that it can send messages using API or the server of the way2sms website.

I have tried, but I get the following errors:

1. First error report.
2. Second error. and so on.

I have also managed to see some code projects to get some more HTTP information and I need some help in sending the message and recieving it, all by the way2sms website service.

#### What you can do

If you asked a question like this, it would have been on topic, which has some basics mentioned:

1. Android Application
2. Google code project sample (if any)
3. Website to be used: way2sms; and their lack of API system.
4. and many other necessary points, such as HTTP requests. You are little bit puzzly though!

Due to these unclear statements, your question was closed! You can edit it anytime, and I guess it will be opened again for answering and you will be able to get an answer to your question!

Comment: I edited my question .. 
Is this it ok now? 
If so i would then flag it for moderators to notice it

Comment: yes, its perfect now! :)

Comment: cant flag it for the second time .. can you flag it or vote up to reopen

Comment: I currently dont have enough rep either to cast a reopen vote, so please contact moderator or stackoverflow team to reopen the question..